# Event of a button which is in a style

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate, wpf-style

Since there isn't a `NumericUpDown`-Control in WPF, i created one using style.

```
<Style x:Key="NumericUpDown" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Grid Width="45" Height="20">
          <TextBox Name="txtBox"
                   TextAlignment="Right"
                   Height="20"
                   Width="30"
                   Margin="0,0,15,0"
                   MaxLength="1"
                   Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                                  Path=Text}"/>
          <Button Name="btnUp"
                  Height="10"
                  Content="▲"
                  Width="15"
                  Margin="30,0,0,10"
                  FontSize="5"/>
          <Button Name="btnDown"
                  Height="10"
                  Content="▼"
                  Width="15"
                  Margin="30,10,0,0"
                  FontSize="5"/>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

(Style code is in App.xaml)

Now I want the buttons to change the value inside the `Textbox`. But I couldn't set their `OnClick` events. Is it possible to set it in code behind, so I don't have to create a style for each control in my window? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should create a `UserControl` or custom control for your numeric up down, and put the logic in the code-behind of that. Possibly you can use template parts as well, naming your buttons as `PART_ButtonUp` and `PART_ButtonDown` to indicate that those buttons have speacial behavior. This follows existing practice of WPF. Some sources: https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/04/template-part-tips/    and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The 'UserControl' may be better i guess. It's a lot easier. I appreciate that!